# Call GeoExt action by click ExtJs button

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext

I have a problem.
I have a ExtJs button and want to call anyone GeoExt action. For example this

```
{xtype:'tbbutton',
                        cls: 'x-btn-icon',
                        id: 'testbutton',
                        tooltip: "Рисовать",
                        icon: url_servlet+'externals/gxp/src/theme/img/silk/delete.png',
                        handler: function(){
                            new GeoExt.Action({
                                text: "max extent",
                                control: new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomToMaxExtent(),
                                map: app.mapPanel.map
                            })
                        }

                      }
```

But its not work and map not zoom to max extent. So where i can mistake. 
 In ideal i want to call action from actionColumn's buttons/
  I will glad if u help/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GeoExt Action is already a button, so there is no need to create the ExtJS button as well. Create the GeoExt action and add it to a toolbar.

```
action = new GeoExt.Action({
    control: new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomToMaxExtent(),
    map: map,
    text: "max extent",
    tooltip: "zoom to max extent"
});
```

http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/toolbar.html

If you just want to have a button on a form to zoom to the max extent of the map, then call the [zoomToMaxExtent](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.zoomToMaxExtent) function directly in the handler:

```
 {
    xtype:'tbbutton',
    cls: 'x-btn-icon',
    id: 'testbutton',
    tooltip: "Рисовать",
    icon: url_servlet+'externals/gxp/src/theme/img/silk/delete.png',
    handler: function(){
        app.mapPanel.map.zoomToMaxExtent();
        })
    }
 }
```

Comment: A week ago i spent whole a day to understand that.